# Как преобразовать вложенные объекты при помощи lodash?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, lodash

```
{ 
  "prop1" : "value",
  "prop2" : {"sub":1}
}
```

А как получить это:

```
{ 
  "prop1" : "value",
  "prop2.sub": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update. Если надо для любого уровня вложенности

```js
function tf(object, prev = '') {
  return _.transform(object, (acc, value, key) => {
    if (_.isPlainObject(value)) Object.assign(acc, tf(value, (prev ? prev + '.' : '') + key));
    else acc[(prev ? prev + '.' : '') + key] = value;
  }, {});
}

console.log(tf({
  "prop1": "value",
  "prop2": {
    "sub": 1,
    "prop3": {
      "sub": 2
    }
  }
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

```js
function tf(object, prev='') {
  return _.transform(object, (acc, value, key) => {
    if (_.isPlainObject(value)) {
      Object.assign(acc, tf(value, (prev ? prev + '.' : '') + key));
    } else acc[(prev ? prev + '.' : '') + key] = value;
  }, {});
}

console.log(tf({
  "prop1": "value",
  "prop2": {
    "sub": 1,
    "prop3": {
      "sub": 2
    }
  }
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

P.S. Работать будет только для одного уровня вложенности.